# Zend: blank screen

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-session

For my work i have to edit a website which has been created with the Zend framework. 
When i deploy them on my test server and browse to the index.php all i get is a blank screen.

I have display_startup_errors and error_reporting turned on and no errors are shown..

Maybe it has something to do with the paths in some files of the website since it has been created by another company which has given me the files after they deployed the website on an actual server.

I really hope someone can help me out.. I have searched through the internet but never found a solution even though multiple people have had my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: put a try catch block and you will get it, or check the log files. You also need some extra libraries for ZF to work, check its requirements

Comment: You should approach this as a generic 'PHP white screen' problem and not zend framework.

Comment: What's in the log file?

Comment: Did you end up fixing this??

I have a similar issue with ZF2 and a form submission leading to a blank screen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have set display_errors and error_reporting in a standard Zend way in the application.ini file and still a white screen then your problem starts before you even get to load the config file.

Add these values *temporarily* to the beginning of your index.php file

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

This should tell you of any errors in the index.php file like path settings.

Comment: This didn't reveal any new errors, I'm going to attempt to just go file to file and compare them with a working version of this project.

Answer (score 0):

The following command (or something similar according to distro) will print out recent errors if your test server is Linux.

```
sudo tail -10 /var/log/httpd/error_log
```

Comment: This file doesn't exist for me, inside Ubuntu 12 LTS... Guessing you're referring to the Apache2 log file.

/var/log/apache2/error.log

Comment: Yeah, it's the Apache log, it varies from system to system.

Answer (score 0):

My blank screen was due to incorrect permissions on my log files (first quoted was application.log).
To track it down I searched my drive for all .log files then ordered by most recent and the error message was one of the latest - file cannot be opened with mode "a" - so I set the permissions on the log files for my site using chmod 777 and the site worked.
The zend folders: application; public; logs; library; all sit under the document root for my site and the files in the logs folder had the wrong permissions assigned (application.log & php_error.log).